# Change extends(layout) dynamically in laravel 5

Tags: layout, laravel-5

I have been trying to change layout dynamically in laravel by just passing a variable in

```
@extends('default1.master')
```

to

```
$var = default2
@extends('$var.master')
```

possibly

```
@extends($var.'.master')
```

tried a lot but unable to find a solution all I get is error in my syntax or view not found.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

in your view you can pass a variable with the view name like

```
@extends('layout.'.$view)
//or
@extends($view.'.base')
```

here $view is a variable which stored the view name from controller my controller looks following

```
$view = 'base';
return view('someview', compact('view'));
```

and if by any chance you are declaring this $var in the view file only you should not forget to enclose it in

```
<?php ?> tag
```