# in Laravel how to change the view content at runtime each time before compilation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

in Laravel 5 I need to amend a view content at runtime before compilation by adding this string: "@extends(foo)"

**note**: changing the view ***file*** content is not an option

so the process will be something like (each time a view is called)

1. getting the view content
2. edit the view content by appending "@extends(foo)" keyword
3. compile (render) the view

I have tried using viewcomposer and middleware with no luck

**here is my composer service provider:**

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {

        View::composer('pages/*', function ($view) {

             // i want to do the following:
             // 1- find all view under directory resources/views/pages
             // 2- then add the following blade command "@extends(foo)" at the beginning of the view before compile

        });

    }


    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**and here is my view middleware try (in middleware i was able to amend view content after compilation :( )**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
class ViewMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response =  $next($request);
        if (!method_exists($response,'content')) {
            return $response;
        }

        $content  = "@extends('layouts.app')".$response->content();
        $response->setContent($content);
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Thanks

**Update**:
what i need to accomplish is to extending views with layouts based on their parent directories

for example my view directory have the following structure

I need the view "controlpanel.blade.php" to have the layout "layout/admin.blade.php" because its parent folder is called "admin"

```
-view
  |--pages
    |--admin
      |--controlpanel.blade.php
  |--layouts
     |--admin.blade.php
```

Comment: What you are trying to do, why is this needed?

Comment: Why don't you include them in your views ?

Comment: for large projects you have to consider moving toward "Convention over configuration". in my case all views are have layouts, so why not automate this. in case if someone have not haired about "Convention over configuration" here is the wikipedia definition:  Convention over configuration (also known as coding by convention) is a software design paradigm used by software frameworks that attempt to decrease the number of decisions that a developer using the framework is required to make without necessarily losing flexibility., hope this clarifies, thanks

Comment: do you always want to append `@extends(foo)` or you want to put it at specific places in the view?

Comment: @RaghavendraN right now my goal is to extend all views under a "resources/view/pages" directory, Thanks

Comment: Just so I understand the requirement, you want `@extends` to search upward through the directories, starting with the same directory as the view, looking for a filename that matches the `@extends` parameter? When found use that as the layout? that way there is no need to dynamically edit the views?

Comment: @RyanVincent exactly, so once i place a view inside the folder "pages/admin" it should automatically extends to the "layouts/admin.blade.php", in other words each view will be extended to a layout named based on its folder name

Comment: Worth adding that explanation to your question - it may help others to appreciate what you want to do? It is, i suspect, easier to implement, and will provide the flexibility you require.

Comment: @ahmed I posted exact solution 2 days ago :-)

Comment: Check [StringBladeCompiler](https://github.com/TerrePorter/StringBladeCompiler), it allows you render view from string template.

Answer (score 3):

Its not easy task. You need to replace Laravel's blade compiler class. It should take main layout from current view path instead of from @extends directive.

config/app.php:
remove original service provider

```
Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class
```

add yours

```
App\Providers\BetterViewServiceProvider::class
```

In your service provider **app/BetterViewServiceProvider.php** the only important thing is to call **\App\BetterBladeCompiler** instead of original Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler, the rest method is copied from parent.

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;


use Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine;
use Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider;

class BetterViewServiceProvider extends ViewServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register the Blade engine implementation.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\View\Engines\EngineResolver  $resolver
     * @return void
     */
    public function registerBladeEngine($resolver)
    {
        $app = $this->app;

        // The Compiler engine requires an instance of the CompilerInterface, which in
        // this case will be the Blade compiler, so we'll first create the compiler
        // instance to pass into the engine so it can compile the views properly.
        $app->singleton('blade.compiler', function ($app) {
            $cache = $app['config']['view.compiled'];

            return new \App\BetterBladeCompiler($app['files'], $cache);
        });

        $resolver->register('blade', function () use ($app) {
            return new CompilerEngine($app['blade.compiler']);
        });
    }
}
```

And now in **app\BetterBladeCompiler.php** override compileExtends methods and change it behaviout in this way that read current path and insert last directory before view file to expression that will be interpreted by other Laravel files.

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler;
use Illuminate\View\Compilers\CompilerInterface;

class BetterBladeCompiler extends BladeCompiler implements CompilerInterface
{
    /**
     * Compile the extends statements into valid PHP.
     *
     * @param  string  $expression
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileExtends($expression)
    {
        // when you want to apply this behaviour only to views from specified directory "views/pages/"
        // just call a parent method
        if(!strstr($this->path, '/pages/')) {
            return parent::compileExtends($expression);
        }

        // explode path to view
        $parts = explode('/', $this->path);

        // take directory and place to expression
        $expression = '\'layouts.' . $parts[sizeof($parts)-2] . '\'';

        $data = "<?php echo \$__env->make($expression, array_except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))->render(); ?>";

        $this->footer[] = $data;

        return '';
    }

}
```

Code from Laravel 5.2. Tested but not too much. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to 'dynamically' extend the views here is a way:

```
$view = 'foo';  // view to be extended
$template = view('home')->nest('variable_name', $view, ['data' => $data]);

return $template->render();
```

And in your view:

```
@if (isset($variable_name))
    {!! $variable_name !!}
@endif
```

This worked for me in Laravel 5.2.

I still think it is easier to organize your views and have them extend the corresponding layouts instead of dynamically passing.

**Edit:**

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30888731/change-extendslayout-dynamically-in-laravel-5#answer-30888864) is another way. But did not check in the latest version of the Laravel.

In your view:

`@extends($view)`

and in controller:

```
$view = 'foo';
return view('someview', compact('view'));
```

Comment: Thanks, your solutions might be of help in other cases ;however, in my case i will not be able to use your solution as it requires configuration, i need to completely avoid any configuration, Thanks

Comment: I did not get what do you mean by configuration. you can place the `if` block anywhere in the View and have your view extend only when you pass the variable

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using laravel blade stacks. Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#stacks

Blade allows you to push to named stacks which can be rendered somewhere else in another view or layout.

So instead of extending 'foo', just push 'foo' view using stacks.

Here are some of the links and discussion for your reference:

[What is the difference between Section and Stack in Blade?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35672485/what-is-the-difference-between-section-and-stack-in-blade)

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/blade-push-and-stack-are-they-here-to-stay

http://laraveltnt.com/blade-stack-push/

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/blade-stacks-pushing-into-an-included-view